# What I'm doing wrong with "useImperative" that i couldn't be able to set my useState value?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col, ButtonGroup, Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Input from '../inputs/Input'

const DetailedPost = (props, ref) => {

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => {
        console.log(show);
        setShow(false);
        console.log(show);
    }

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        openModal: () => setShow(true),

    }));

    return (

        <Modal size='lg' show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Container fluid className='d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between'>
                    <Row >
                        <Col lg={6}>
                            <Container className='mt-1 border'>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col lg={12} className='d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-1 border-bottom'>
                                        <Col lg={11} className='d-flex align-items-center py-2'>

                                            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/User_icon_2.svg/330px-User_icon_2.svg.png" alt="" style={{ width: '30px' }} />
                                            <span className='fw-bolder ms-3'>Ashlok Chaudhary <br /> <span className='text-muted'>Mumbai, Maharashtra</span></span>

                                        </Col>
                                        <Button variant='light'><i className="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i></Button>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col lg={12} className='mt-2 mb-2'>
                                        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates animi vero laboriosam natus voluptas.
                                            Inventore odio tempore odit et sed facere labore accusantium possimus, deserunt aut, nulla aliquam,
                                            deleniti sequi. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                                            Delectus vitae distinctio deleniti eos quam praesentium facere, dolorum qui quidem.
                                            Ipsum placeat neque eaque eveniet facilis suscipit, quisquam unde labore impedit.
                                            Quidem magnam accusantium excepturi neque deleniti, repellendus vitae perspiciatis,
                                            voluptates cum ab voluptatem tempora numquam libero sapiente, nostrum omnis similique?</p>

                                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695799561-033f55f75b25?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
                                            alt="" className='img-fluid border' />
                                    </Col>
                                    <ButtonGroup className='d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between'>
                                        <Button variant='light'>
                                            <i className="fa-regular fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button variant='light'>
                                            <i className="fa-solid fa-comments"></i>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button variant='light'>
                                            <i className="fa-solid fa-retweet"></i>
                                        </Button>
                                    </ButtonGroup>
                                </Row>
                            </Container>
                        </Col>

                        <Col lg={6}>
                            <Container className='mt-3 mb-3 border rounded-4'>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col lg={12} className='py-2 border-bottom'>
                                        <h6 className='fw-bolder text-decoration-underline link-offset-2'>Comments</h6>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col lg={12} style={{ maxHeight: '70vh' }}>
                                        {/* Comments should appears here..... */}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col lg={12} className='d-flex align-items-center py-2'>
                                        <Input inputType='text' inputClassName='form-control py-2 rounded-0' placeholder='Write Something...' />
                                        <Button variant='light' className='rounded-0 ms-2'> <i className="fa-regular fa-paper-plane fs-4"></i></Button>
                                    </Col>

                                </Row>
                            </Container>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
    )
}

export default forwardRef(DetailedPost);
```

Basically, I'm building an project where when user click on specific post then the modal pop's up in that modal full post details are shows up. I'm not much familiar with **useImperative** hook but want to use it.
The modal is open's up properly but the handleClose couldn't be able to set the state value ?
Can anyone help me to fix this or guide me with using **useImperative** hook or what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: keep in mind, `handleClose` in your case will output `true` and `true`, and that's expected. `setShow` will not change the value synchronously, if you want to see the "current" value, you would need to put it in the render function.

Comment: Hmm, You are right !

Comment: Note `useImperativeHandle` is really an escape hatch and you shouldn't really be used in this scenario, as it would be considered unusual.  You would usually solve this problem by passing an open prop (boolean) from the component above and managing that state there. If there needs to be interaction with some state from a parent component, the usual thing to do is to hoist that state to the parent and pass it through props. For more details, see the "pitfall" note at the bottom of the docs, https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle#:~:text=Show%20more-,Pitfall,-Do%20not%20overuse

Comment: In fact, by chance, the docs even point out your use case as one to avoid using `useImperativeHandle` with!